# Is it noticeably faster to filter by an integer compared to a string in ElasticSearch?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have 3 item archetypes in my app, `Weapon`, `Armour`, `Misc`.

A user can only search in one category at a time for now. So, I was wondering if I should index the archetype as an integer (0, 1, 2), or as a string `"weapon"`, `"armour"`, `"misc"`?

I'm using a boolean query. Will it be faster to filter by an integer, a string, or is there almost no difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference.

Ensure it's actually a filter you use. Then it'll be cached as a bitmap, and just as fast on later uses.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that a filter has no effect on facets if I remember correctly, and I would display wrong counts.

Comment: Use the `filtered` query, not `filter` on the search object, renamed to `post_filter` in 1.0 for precisely these confusions :)